# Check and use a certain item if it exists in my data structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, matching

I have a list of items, e.g.

```
item_list = ['char_model_..._main', 'char_model_..._main_default', 'char_rig_..._main', 'char_rig_..._main_default',  'char_acc__..._main']
```

While I am able to get certain things I wanted from the list and I code it as follows (not in a very dignified way, but it gives me feedback):

```
item_wanted=[]
for item in item_list:
    if item.startswith("char_model") and (item.endswith("main") or item.endswith("main_default")):
        item_wanted.append(item)
```

So while I am able to get the items I wanted such that now `my item_wanted` list contains `'char_model_..._main', 'char_model_..._main_default'`, how should I code it such that if `'main'` exists, use it otherwise use `'main_default'`?

Comment: Split your long condition into multiple `if`s?

Comment: One option would be to iterate again over `items_wanted`. But why do you use a list of results at all?

Comment: I tried a version without a list result, because I understand that you are actually interested in one end result. The problem with a list result is that you get multiple matches, on the other hand: if you use only one variable, good results can overwritten by worse ones. So have a look how to [do it using two variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40418469/2932052).

Comment: Use a dict or set, not a list. Moreover, use a hierarchical dict-of-dicts, so that 'char_model' is at the first level, then '...' at the second level, and so on. Also see `Collections.defaultdict` as it implements the default functionality. Take a look at other questions on converting a flat list into a dict-of-dicts.

Answer (score 0):

well, I am not absolutely got your intention, but maybe you can try to split it

```
if item.startswith("char_model") :
  if item.endswith("main"):
    #do your thing if its "char_model...main"
  elif item.endswith("main_default):
    #do your thing if its "char_model...main"
```

hope this helps

Comment: If you do this in a loop, you'll get both results again.

Answer (score 0):

Split the items that are valid into those containing *default* and those not containing. After that, iterate the ones that **do** end in *default* and try to find that same key on the other list (removing the end of course). If it's not there, it means that we have to resort to using the default, if it is, we leave it as is is.

```
item_wanted  = []
item_default = []

for item in item_list:
    if item.startswith("char_model"):
        if item.endswith("main_default"):
            item_default.append(item)
        elif item.endswith("main"):
            item_wanted.append(item)

for potential in item_default:
    if potential[:-8] not in item_wanted: #Look for the key without default
        item_wanted.append(potential)     #Append it if not present
```

Comment: looks quite complicated to see the implementation matching the actual need. I tried a more direct projection of the *prefer `x_main` to `x_main_default`* pattern.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to **use simply two variables** and one iteration about the input list. It's able to cope with multiple *"good"* and *"best"* matches in the input. For simplification, I used lists of numbers, and, for the `main` and `main_default` part, I used to prefer 1 to 2.

Code:

```
def match(items):
    found1 = None
    found2 = None
    for i in items:
        if (i==1):
            found1 = i
        elif (i==2):
            found2 = i
    return found1 or found2

print (match([2,1]))
print (match([3,2]))
print (match([4,3]))
```

Output:

```
1
2
None
```

<sub>see this running at https://ideone.com/bBj5Op</sub>